# How to show a set of vectors is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having my final tomorrow for linear algebra and I don't think I fully understand how to show a set of vectors is a subspace.  I had a question in a test which had $H = \{[a b c], abc=0\}$
the $[a b c]$ is a $3\times 1$ matrix, not a $[1\times 3]$ as I wrote it.

Obviously, the zero vector, $a=b=c=0$ is in $H$, so $abc$ is on the origin.

Suppose there is some other vector such, say, $d_1(abc)=0$.  so $c_1(abc) + d_1(abc) = 0$. So $H$ is in closed under addition.

but how do I show that abc=0 is not closed under scalar multiplication?  Please, explain to me exactly how it works?

Comment: We have $v=[1,1,0]$ and $w=[0,0,1]$ in $H$, because $abc=0$ for their coefficients. But $v+w=[111]$ is not in $H$. Scalar multiplies, however, are again in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

$abc$ is not a vector. It's a real number. In your notation, $[a, b, c]$ is a vector. In order to prove that this set is a vector space, you should prove that, **whenever** $a_1b_1c_1=0$ and $a_2b_2c_2=0$, and $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R$, **then** $(\lambda a_1+\mu a_2)(\lambda b_1+\mu b_2)(\lambda c_1+\mu c_2)=0$, which is what $$[a_1,b_1,c_1],[a_2,b_2,c_2]\in H\implies \lambda[a_1,b_1,c_1]+\mu[a_2,b_2,c_2]\in H$$ means.

Hint: it's not true.